# iOS to parse JSON?

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I am getting the following response from server

```
[{"id":"16","name":"Bob","age":"37"},{"id":"17","name":"rob","age":"28"}];
```

I am using `AFNetworking` framework for it,

I am getting the above response in `NSData` and then using the the below code, I am able to collect the data in `NSDictionary`

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

But how to parse the `"name"` and `"age"` value from that `NSDictionary`?

Comment: you can also use in this format too `[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You expected NSDictionary but your response gives you array of dictionaries, try this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@, age: %@", dict[@"name"], dict[@"age"]);
}
```

//Extended

From the comment below it looks like you have a string from the response, not NSArray as you show in the code above.
You can parse string to get the data you want or you can convert it back to the json and NSArray:

```
    NSString * jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
   //As I post above
```

Now you should have an NSArray and my code should do the job.

Comment: i have tried this but the app crashes with the following error message
 "[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]"

Comment: it's not NSArray bcoz m trying to use the count funct.....but the app crashes
[__NSCFString count]:

so i think its not NSArray

Comment: This error says that it's not an array but NSString object. But the code you show says clear that's NSArray. Can you call: id data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error]; NSLog(@"CLASS: %@", NSStringFromClass([data class]); And let me know what is the output.

Comment: it says this CLASS: __NSCFString

its nsstring class

Comment: thanks.....you save my day.......
Is this a right way to parse a json?
can it parse huge amount of data?